# First line in new file is missing when use open() and .write

Tags: python-3.x

I have txt file with some text. From this file I try to get what I need and save it into new file. If I save everything into one file it's working. But if I try save it into few files then first part of first line in new file is missing.

```
file_out = open("Words 01-24.txt", "w")

with open("raw.txt", "r") as file_in:
    new_line = file_in.readline()

    index = 0
    while new_line:
        if "dictionary" in new_line:
            file_out.write(f"some text {index} ")
        elif "definition" in new_line:
            file_out.write("some text\n")
            index += 1

        if index % 25 == 0 and index != 0:
            file_out.close()
            file_out = open(f"Words {index}-{index + 24}.txt", "w")

        new_line = file_in.readline()

file_out.close()
```

In new file fist line is "some text" instead of "some text 25 some text".

Comment: Can I see the first 25 lines of raw.txt to help diagnose the problem?

Comment: First 25 cases cover over 400 lines in raw.txt file are you sure you want it?

Comment: For clarify, I did check that if statement is working fine (using print) the problem is file_out.write, after pair file_out.close() file_out = open(), it print inside if "dictionary" so it's triggered but file_out.write don't write inside file, even when I try with two separate file_out.write (inside if "dict") none of them working.

Comment: There text from raw.txt that cover first 25 cases: https://pastebin.com/JAhsJMUy and logic that need to be put inside both .write() new_line[new_line.find("\">")+2:new_line.find("</")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Empty strings are `False` - so it will not go into your while loop if your first line is empty.
- In case neither `'dictionary'` nor `'definition'` are in a *non-empty* line, nothing is written.

I would probably change the code to:

```
fn = "raw.txt"
names =["Words 01-24.txt"]    
file_out = open(names[-1], "w")

with open(fn) as file_in: 
    index = 0
    for new_line in file_in:

        if "dictionary" in new_line:
            file_out.write(f"some text {index} ")
        elif "definition" in new_line:
            file_out.write("some text\n")
            index += 1
            file_used = True
        elif not new_line.strip():  # only spaces or \r or \n or other whitespaces
            print("empty line") 
        else:
            print(f"line with other content: {new_line}")

        # only create a new file if the current one was already 
        # written into
        if index % 25 == 0 and index != 0 and file_used:
            file_out.close()
            names.append(f"Words {index}-{index + 24}.txt")
            file_used = False

            file_out = open(names[-1], "w")    
file_out.close()

for n in names:
    print(n, open(n).read(), sep="\n================\n")
```

(File) Output:

```
Words 01-24.txt
================
some text 0 some text
some text 1 some text
some text 2 some text
some text 3 some text
some text 4 some text
some text 5 some text
some text 6 some text
some text 7 some text
some text 8 some text
some text 9 some text
some text 10 some text
some text 11 some text
some text 12 some text
some text 13 some text
some text 14 some text
some text 15 some text
some text 16 some text
some text 17 some text
some text 18 some text
some text 19 some text
some text 20 some text
some text 21 some text
some text 22 some text
some text 23 some text
some text 24 some text

Words 25-49.txt
================
some text 25 some text
some text 26 some text
some text 27 some text
```